# how to use libavformat/movenccenc.c ffmpeg ibrary for video encryption?

Tags: encryption, video, ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

**FFmpeg** support video encryption using functions defined in `libavformat/movenccenc.h`. However, there isn't sufficient documentation about how to use the library functions.

For example: in the function:

```
int ff_mov_cenc_init (
    MOVMuxCencContext *ctx,
    uint8_t *encryption_key,
    int use_subsamples,
    int bitexact);
```

What is `MOVMuxCencContext`

How should I proceed with the video encryption if I want to use C/C++ for this task?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This file `movenccenc.c/h` is actually a helper for mov mp4 muxer `movenc.c`.
According to `movenc.c`, encryption mechanism triggered by this parameter:

```
{ "encryption_scheme",    "Configures the encryption scheme, allowed values are none, cenc-aes-ctr", offsetof(MOVMuxContext, encryption_scheme_str),   AV_OPT_TYPE_STRING, {.str = NULL}, .flags = AV_OPT_FLAG_ENCODING_PARAM },
```

And currently only allowed value is (string) `"cenc-aes-ctr"`.

Hope that helps.